# Python script continues after killing the execution

Tags: python, keras, spyder

I train a neuronal network and when executing the script it seems to stop after some time. 
Nothing is printed out anymore (for more than 20 minutes and normally it prints nearly every second something).

So I thought something would be wrong and kill the execution via the quadratical button. 
And immediately after pressing it, the execution continues!?

There is no exception occured or something simular. It seems like coming out of nothing.

But after pressing the button it continues just for a short time, like 5 seconds, then it stops fully (without reaching the end of the script). Maybe because I pressed the button?

First I thought Spyder IDE could be the reason, maybe it doesnt work properly. So I tested JupyterLab but it happens exactly the same!

Can anyone help me? I would be extremely glad if it would work...
Do you need the code (Its really long) or some other information I forgot?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevertheless I dont understand why the execution continued after pressing the stopbutton, I assume that the reason for the strange behaviour is due to a wrong implemented while-loop. I forgot a break-statement in a nested if-clause.

Presumably I am pretty sure the execution of py-scripts and jar-files is basically different. In Java (I am still used to Java) the consoleprinting would never had continued after stopping the execution. :D
And exactly this is what made me searching for something different to be the reason than a coding error.

However, after correcting the mistake it works properly.

Comment: That's got nothing to do witha while loop. Most libraries, especially for deep neural networks, are parallelized, and it often takes some time to halt them since the keyboard interruption command "waits" for all processes or threads to end. That is why it sometimes continues even after killing it. Dou you work on windows? Then there is a large bunch of windoof-related issues that ma cause longer delays. I assume that your while loop was executed in one loop, producing probably a dead lock or something. Does it help using the killing command twice?

Comment: I use Windows 7. Indeed, adding the missing break-statement fixed the issue. Therefore I assume it was the reason - although I find it really strange that it then continues after killing the execution.

Comment: Maybe, check out your python and keras versions etc. and try to report this behaviour to the respective developers, it really might be a bug in one of the libraries, since this is so unusual. I think its strange that your problem attracted only so few attention. Maybe also post the code snippet that causes the trouble.